# In ANSI C,const values are global?

Tags: c, constants, global

I read from a C++ book that  In ANSI C, const values are global? but if i declare a const variable in `main()` then it will be locally scoped then how we can say that const are global?

Comment: Could you please identify the book that says this, and be more exact on what and how it says it? Also ANSI C is usually not a very precise term. ANSI follows the ISO C standard, so there are at least three different versions, C89, C99 and C11.

Comment: The author is probably trying to say that file-scope `const` variables without a storage-class specifier have external linkage in C, whereas they default to internal linkage in C++. Block-scope variables have no linkage by default in both languages.

Comment: Every segment in c is having read only area.Const will indicate compiler to put that into read only area.

Comment: Yes, if it is a variable declared in `main()`, it is a local variable in `main()`. But that is a variable. A const value, that can mean `7`, or `"Hello World"` etc... Please stop reading that book, and if you see other people reading it, tell them to stop. "In ANSI C, const values are global" what the heck is that even supposed to mean???

Answer (score 5):

There is no global lexical scope in C but there is a file scope. The `const` qualification of an object does not affect its scope.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 0;         // file scope
const int b = 0;   // file scope

int main(void)
{
    int x;        // block scope
    const int y;  // block scope
}
```

Comment: means book is wrong @ouah???  and as u are saying int a=0; is file scoped i don't think so bcoz we can use a in different file using extern int a;with including this file..isn't it?

Comment: It may be worth to note that in addition both `a` and `b` variables have _external linkage_, which is commonly refered as "global variable". Only `static` keyword can change linkage to internal (but only for variables declared outside of any function, these declared inside have no linkage), `const` is not affecting anything in this regard (as well as for variables declared inside functions).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski means it is wrong "In ANSI C, const values are global?" bcoz it may be block scope also..isn't it?

Comment: @user2487315: It does not matter where it's declared. `const` qualifier is simply unrelated.

Comment: @user2487312: Either the book is wrong (many books are), or you misunderstood  what it was saying.  All `const` does is make a variable read-only; it doesn't affect scope.

Comment: File scoped variables should be declared `static`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès did you downvote with this point? No, file scope variable should not be declared as static. They should be declared static only if they are private to the translation unit where they are declared, if you intend to make them visible to other translation units you cannot declare them as static.

Comment: No. Right for file scoping: it is explicitly mentioned in the standard.